# Increment NSDate for use in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I am looking for a way to write a for loop that iterates over an NSDate.  Each loop should increment the NSDate by 10 seconds.

I want to have 2 timestamps. Say timestamp A is Midnight Monday and timestamp B is Midnight Tuesday.

What I then want is some code to say for A to B incrementing at 10 second intervals between the two points in time, use the timestamp at current position, and the timestamp at the last position, so I can run a query based on the intervals.

Would someone be so good as to show me how I would do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Are you saying that you want to run a query every 10 seconds? Or are you saying that you want to create an array of dates that are each 10 seconds apart? If you had an array of dates, how would you use those in a query?

Comment: Sorry! I want to loop through an array 10 seconds apart between two periods, so I can use those values to query other data between those interim periods.

Comment: So, between 00:00:00 Monday and 00:00:00 Tuesday, I want to loop through 00:00:00, 00:00:10, 00:00:20, 00:00:30 through to 23:59:50

Comment: Why do you want us to do your job? Try to write code using NSDate and then add it to the question if you will have some problems.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is how to increment an NSDate in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for loop needs three parts, an initialisation, a compare, and an increment. It could look like this:

```
for (NSDate *date = startDate;                    // initialisation
    [date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending; // compare
    date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:10])    // increment
{
    // do something with date here, eg:
    NSDate *rangeStart = date;
    NSDate *rangeEnd = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];

    [runQuery begin:rangeStart end:rangeEnd];
}
```

You might prefer to refactor to use a while loop so that the dateByAddingTimeInterval doesn't need to be repeated.

This is the same structure as a normal for loop:

```
for (int i = 0;  // initialisation
     i < 10;     // compare
     i++)        // increment
{
    // do something with i here
}
```

Comment: Douglas, that is exactly what I wanted! date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:10])    // increment I have been staring at it and missing it completely! Long day I think. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may want to look into [NSTimer's timerWithTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a).  The interface looks like this:

```
+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

and then you can start one ten seconds later using:

```
initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
```

You can sign up for a call that is sent every seconds as shown below:

```
// SomeClass.m

#import "SomeClass.h"
@interface ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer timer1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer timer2;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    NSDate* date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
    self.timer1 = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.timer2 = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date interval:10 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  if (timer == self.timer1) {
    NSLog(@"timer1 fired");
  }
}
@end
```

Comment: JuJoDi Thanks for this. It was the loop as Douglas stated that I wanted. However, very useful description of the timerWithTimeInterval. Thank you.